# MySQL query based replication

Tags: mysql, replication, binary-log

I wish to road-test a MySQL Cluster instance by passing it all query which are executed on InnoDB MySQL instance. I'm not too worried about data integrity on the Cluster at present, this study is focused on the stability and speed of the Cluster.

I do not wish to use statement-based binary log replication as queries which are purely SELECT will not get passed to the Cluster and so will give an incomplete view on performance.

What is the best method for implementing General Query Log based replication between MySQL instances?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question!

There is http://www.electricmonk.nl/Programmings/MyQryReplayer , but it doesn't meet your needs, as it doesn't work online (i.e. in near real time).

Answer (score 0):

you could use myqsl proxy to send the queries to both servers.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK SELECT statements are not logged in the log-bin, only UPDATES and INSERTS. The only way I know to log select queries is thru the mysql-proxy.